# Adobe InDesign JSX: get Data Merge Link or File

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have an INDD document in which I added a csv data source using the Data Merge panel. I can see the data source in the Links Panel. How do I fetch this specific link/file using javascript?

I have explored the [DataMerge object model](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_DataMerge.html) and the [Link object model](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Link.html) for potential access points, but nothing jumped out at me.

I could iterate the links and pick out unplaced links, but I worry about false positives. For example, if another script created an unplaced link, the way Data Merge does.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

for ( var i = 0; i < doc.links.length; i++ )
{
    var link = doc.links[i];

    if ( link.parent == doc )
    {
        alert( link.filePath );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would sat that assets placed into the document will have a specific parent. A story for text based files, an Image Object for images links.
Link which parent is Document is probably the one you are looking for.
CSV files also have a "XML" linkType property value FWIW. It's likely that if one loads and link a XML file (wml workflow), the link will also have a "XML" linkType value but the parent would then be the XMLElement Object. 
For tabbed text, parent property should be trustable enough.